# Laravel radio button with dynamic name from database table ID

Tags: php, laravel

seeking for help. I don't know how to do this in controller. I have question and choices table. I perfectly fetch from database both question and choice data to display blade file.

Now, I am saving the data in the database but I don't know how should I do this. Should I need to make different table for the answer of the user?

Please my code below.

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
     <label for="name">{{$question->question}}</label>
     @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
        <input id="{{$choice->id}}" type="radio" value="{{$choice->id}}" name="choices_[{{$question->id}}]">
        <label for="{{$choice->id}}">{{$choice->choice}}</label>
     @endforeach   
@endforeach
```

[image]

Thank you hope anyone can help.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Based on what I understood, you already created the tables for questions and choices. Is the part you want help about saving the question with the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to keep track of answers. If you choose 'yes,' then each answer will include the answer the user selected, the ID of the question, a field indicating whether it's correct or not, and the user's ID. After the user submits the answer, you save this information.

If the user can take this quiz multiple times, and you want to store the results of each quiz separately, you'll need another table, which you could name 'quiz_attempts.' The answers will reference these quiz attempts, and you can store the score in this table.